# How to resize an image used inside a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a clickable image that plays a sound when you click it using a code I found here in SO.

This  works just fine, but I want to place the image in another part of the screen and resize it.

I want the image to have `width="300" height="210" style="margin-left: 1300px;">`,  but I don't know how to implement it into the JS code, or if i should do something else to fix this.

Any suggestions? I haven't tried anything to fix it just yet because I have no idea of just what should I do, since my knowledge is still very basic

```
<div>
    <script>
        var audio = new Audio("https://files.catbox.moe/23r8yv.mp3");
        audio.oncanplaythrough = function ( ) { }
        audio.onended = function ( ) { }
     </script>
    <input type="image" src="https://felizcumpleanos.neocities.org/cosas%20para%20cumplea%C3%B1os/mewo%20fondo%20mimi.png" onclick="audio.play ( )">
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: If you want to add styles to the input you should assign a class or use inline styles. You dont need javascript for that. Like that: <input style="width: 300px; height: 210px; margin-left: 1300px;" type="image" src="https://felizcumpleanos.neocities.org/cosas%20para%20cumplea%C3%B1os/mewo%20fondo%20mimi.png" onclick="audio.play ( )">

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the HTML and add some styling to the image. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
<div>
    <script>
        var audio = new Audio("https://files.catbox.moe/23r8yv.mp3");
        audio.oncanplaythrough = function () { }
        audio.onended = function () { }
    </script>
    <input type="image" src="https://felizcumpleanos.neocities.org/cosas%20para%20cumplea%C3%B1os/mewo%20fondo%20mimi.png"
           onclick="audio.play()" style="width: 300px; height: 210px; margin-left: 1300px;">
</div>
```